# How to navigate on the same page without scrolling ANGULAR?

Tags: angular

Is there any way to navigate on the same page without scrolling?
I tried this in angular but it doesn't work it sends me to a url that doesn't exist.

```
<a href="#bottom">Go to bottom</a>

<div id="bottom"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code from `ng-click` function for going to bottom of html page

```
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight || document.documentElement.scrollHeight);
```